# NT4 server generate too much weird DNS queries, How can i see the source PID?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a NT4 server that in the last two weeks started to generate too many weird DNS queries to the DNS server is set to use. I have got warnings from the IPS system that it has blocked the responses from the DNS server back to the NT4 server.

The queries it generate doesn't relate to any computer in the network, it is like `120624100088.xxxxxxx.net` where `xxx` is the internal network, the numbers are just random at each query.

I have done some research on how to get the PID that is generating the queries, and i found that only Process Monitor could give me that information, but since it is NT4 system Process Monitor doesn't work on it.

It is a production server and i am just can't stop services as i want.

I would like to get your advice on how can i get the PID that is generating these queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

netstat command (command-line) can give you the PID's of the processes too.
You may have to run it a number of times as it makes a snapshot of the state of the network connections. That snapshot may just miss the ones you are actually interested it.

You may have to fiddle with the options to the command. Definitely use -n because that greatly speeds up the processing. (You are looking for DNS so you can just filter out any output not refering to port 53 and the ip-address of the DNS server.)
If the process turns out to be svchost.exe then you will have to use Process Monitor or a similar utility (I believe ProcesExplorer from SysInternals still works in NT4, you may have to find an old version of it) to determine which processes are using svchost as intermediary.

Just one question though.... NT4 ?... connected to the Internet ?.... Somebody should be shot for that.

Comment: NT4  not connected. Somebody could give me  the syntax for netstat?

Comment: The precursors of Process Monitor were FileMon and RegMon. Process Explorer is something entirely different. And AFAIR the `netstat` command on Windows didn't support showing the PID before Windows XP. [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) may be able to provide that information, though.

Comment: I found the `CurrPorts` program from NirSoft, it seems to have more information than TCPView, since to me TCPView couldn't help much.